# Cut/paste based off of RBG color

Tags: excel, vba

The first macro creates four worksheets, names them, then searches the original worksheet for string words and colors them based off of RBG and sort them. I never have an issue running this macro.

My second macro should cut/paste things into their specified worksheet. It never works.

Macro 1 that creates worksheets, color codes, and sorts.

```vb
Sub MacroTest3()

' MacroTest3 Macro
'

'
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "DNIF"
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Wx"
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Preg"
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Sheets("Sheet4").Name = "<30"
Range("G34").Select
Sheets("Down Weekly").Select
Range("A1:A2").Select
Selection.Copy
Cells.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DNIF").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("C:C").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("D:F").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("E:I").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Rows("1:3").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Cells.Select   '------ selects all cell command!

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Looks for string "Waiver Log" then colors it Yellow
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Waiver Log", _
    TextOperator:=xlContains
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Looks for string "Waiver Hold" then colors it Yellow
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Waiver Hold", _
    TextOperator:=xlContains
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Looks for string "Pregn" then colors it Red
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="Pregn", _
    TextOperator:=xlContains
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Sorts less than 30 days then colors cels orange
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=D2>TODAY()-31"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Sorts Red cells to the top, yellow cells bellow it:
Sheets("DNIF").Select
Range("A1:G1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DNIF").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DNIF").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("G2:G1000"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 0 _
    , 0)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DNIF").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("G2:G1000"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
    255, 0)
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DNIF").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("D2:D1000"), _
    xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
    192, 0)
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DNIF").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:G1000")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Copies the headers onto the different worksheets
Range("A1:G1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Wx").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Preg").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("<30").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Second Macro to cut/paste rows based off of RBG color

```vb
Sub Copier()

Dim TransIDField As Range
Dim TransIDCell As Range
Dim OriginSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetSheet2 As Worksheet

Set OriginSheet = Worksheets("Down Weekly")
Set TransIDField = OriginSheet.Range("G2", OriginSheet.Range("G2").End(xlDown))
Set TargetSheet = Worksheets("Preg")
Set TargetSheet2 = Worksheets("Wx")

For Each TransIDCell In TransIDField
    If TransIDCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        TransIDCell.Resize(1, 7).Cut Destination:= _
            TargetSheet.Range("A1").Offset(TargetSheet.Rows.Count - 1, 
0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next TransIDCell

For Each TransIDCell In TransIDField
   If TransIDCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
        TransIDCell.Resize(1, 7).Cut Destination:= _
            TargetSheet2.Range("A1").Offset(TargetSheet2.Rows.Count - 1, 
0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
   End If
Next TransIDCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Whenever you do `Sheets.Add` it is very important to specify which workbook you want to add the sheet onto. You can use built in keywords like `ThisWorkbook` or `ActiveWorkbook` to reference the one you want. Otherwise, look for the workbook by name in `Application.Workbooks` like `Application.Workbooks("Report.xlsm").Sheets.Add`

Comment: When you do `Sheets.Add` the new worksheet is returned by the method. You can save that worksheet object as a variable for later use: `Set DataSheet = Sheets.Add`. This will then let you do the rest of your code using that variable. like `DataSheet.Name = "New Name"`

Comment: I think reading [How to avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/16578424) would help you to refactor esp. your first macro. Then I would split the first macro in subs per each task. And then it will be much easier to understand and fix the errors

Comment: You don't need to `Select` a sheet to rename it, you can safely remove all of the `Sheet.Select` lines.

Comment: If in the future you DO need to select a cell for whatever reason, you can save coding time, messiness, confusion, and what-not by turning :    `Sheets("<30").Select & Range("A1").Select` into `Sheets("<30").Range("A1").Select`